# Google Map Image API Ajax call

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

My question is

1. Can we make a Ajax Post call to Google map image API , where we can send n no. of markers details and get a result as map image showing all markers on Map.
2. If we cannot make Ajax post call to Google map image API, then is their any alternate way where we can save Google map with n no. of markers on it as image(png/jpeg) .

Please help me .

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the Static Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: Definitely Yes, i want to use Google Static Map, but is their any alternate solution to overcome limitation in number of markers.